# shasum of saved (using tf.keras.model.save_weights()) hdf5 files not matching (deterministic model)

Tags: tensorflow2.0, hdf5

I am working on a personal project, that should be deterministic in nature.

After each batch during training, model will go to next state like how finite state machines work. So no matter how many times model is trained from scratch, it will go through same states and finally it will reach final state.

So I am following this

```
init state = compile_model_and_save_model() // I am using tf.keras.model.save_weights(). I cannot use model.save() as my model is custom subclassed model

for 2-3 training runs: // note I am using training runs instead of epoch because I am training from scratch every time
  model.load_weights() // loading init state
  model.fit() // after this model reaches final state
  model.save_weights() // save trained model in other location

check_shasum_of_trained_hdf5_model_file()
```

I can't get sha sums to match with each other which means trained hdf5 files between each runs are different from each other. But further inspection suggests that each time model reaches the same final state.

1. So does hdf5 files save some kind of metadata like (time of dumping) which causes shasums to not match or am I missing something else?
2. Also how can I check if intermediate steps taken by model always remains same? (a code snippet would be great)

Please help!

Comment: This stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019656/hdf5-file-h5py-with-version-control-hash-changes-on-every-save?rq=1) will answer first question.